# Reindex on empty Solr core

Tags: solr, sunspot-rails

running Solr in Docker container and accessing it using sunspot_rails gem. Created empty core in Solr container:

`solr create -c app`

this is my `sunspot.yaml`

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: solr
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/app
```

when I run `rake sunspot:solr:reindex` getting this error:

```
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request
Error: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"undefined field type",
    "code":400}}

URI: http://solr:8983/solr/app/update?wt=json
Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/json"}
Request Data: "{\"delete\":{\"query\":\"type:Form\"}}"
```

How to reindex with the empty core?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem using `recipedude/solr-sunspot` Docker image.
Read more about this issue:

- https://github.com/recipedude/solr-sunspot
- https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/916